# Cloning of temporary in c++?

Tags: c++, clone

I have a situation where I have the following, briefly:

```
class K {
  K clone() const{K cl; /* clone this to cl then */ return cl; }
};
K* call_clone()
{
  K k;
  return new K(k.clone());
}
```

after compiler optimization, will this be doubly copied?

Alternatively:
Would be an implementation with `C*clone()` more efficient?

Like this:

```
class K {
  K* clone() const { K*p=new K(); /* clone this to *p then */ return p; }
};
K* call_clone()
{
  K k;
  return k.clone();
}
```

(I ask this because even a shallow copy of K could be costly, it will be a class data struct in practice.)

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit about C++ *Copy Constructors*, and possibly also *References*

Comment: @Roddy: For the second case — not necessarily. A `clone()` as in his second example may be necessary when using polymorphism. You can see that type of things all over in languages like Java, C# etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after compiler optimization, will this be doubly copied?

It depends upon the compiler. Any modern compiler will not perform a double copy, this is called a [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). It does not depend on whether the definition of `clone()` is available or not.

> Would be an implementation with C*clone() more efficient?

No, it won't. Dynamic memory management (operators new/delete and alike) are very expensive. It might be even more expensive than performing a double-copy, depending on what your copy-constructor actually does.

Comment: Note that RVO is a bit fragile, so you need to learn how/when a compiler will optimize it.  However, `move`-return is pretty robust: if you return a local variable, the compiler can (and usually does) `move`.  Implement a fast `K(K&&)` move constructor, and `call_clone` will call at most 2 moves.  The `pImpl` pattern can get you fast move constructors at the cost of some overhead at other times.  You might want to work out what your semantics for `K` copy/move and make sure they are simple and understandable...  `K clone()` should be a copy constructor, shouldn't it?

Comment: The reason to use `C* clone()`, rather than just `C clone()`, has nothing to do with optimization.  If you just want to copy an object whose type is known at compile time, you use the copy constructor, directly.  You don't use a function `clone` unless you need the dynamic dispatch.  And that pretty much means returning a pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes it has. If you happened to have a compiler with no RVO, and a copying twice was more expensive than calling a `new` and copying just once, then you would have been better off with `clone()`. But it is hard to imagine this kind of scenario IRL these days.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional `clone()` creates a copy on the heap, e.g.:

```
T* clone() { return new T(*this); }
```

Otherwise one could simply call the copy constructor.

So, `call_clone()` should look something like:

```
K* call_clone() {
    K k;
    return k.clone();
}
```

> after compiler optimization, will this be doubly copied?

If `clone()` definition is available (the function is inline or generated from a template) a compiler may optimize away creating the local variable and copying.

Comment: Is there such a thing as 'traditional clone' in C++?

Comment: well, OpenCV `cv::Mat` has `cv::Mat clone() const;`

Comment: @Roddy: Yes and no. There have been countless attempts at standardising a deep-copying owning smart pointer, usually called `value_ptr`, and the big obstacle has always been the nature of a purported `clone()` function.

Comment: @Roddy I'd say yes.  I've seen the function in just about every project I've worked on, for more than twenty years.  Always with the same semantics (and always virtual, so that the cloned object would have the same dynamic type as the object being cloned).  In Windows shops, it's occasionally called `Clone`, instead of `clone`, but other than that, it's probably one of the most ubiquitous C++ idioms.

Comment: @JamesKanze : Thanks, that all makes sense. I've learnt stuff today, then ;-)